# Implementing strings and the OR function (||) in an if statement

Tags: c#, string, if-statement

I am currently trying to make an if statement to validate a string. This is currently what I have.

```
Console.Write("Please enter your phone number: ");
string input = Console.ReadLine();

if (input.Length < 9)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Phone number is not valid, please try again.");
}

string everythingButThePlus = input.Substring(1);
string justThePlus = input.Substring(0, 1);

if (justThePlus = "+" || "1" || "2" || "3" || "4" || "5" || "6" || "7" || "8" || "9" || "0") ;
{

}
Console.ReadLine();
```

The portion, "justThePlus = "+" ||" is currently got a red underline with the description being,

> "Operator '||' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and
>   'string'.

If I can't use OR statements, what is an alternative that works with strings?

Comment: You should read about the basics of programming.

Answer (score 12):

You're almost there:

```
if (justThePlus == "+" || justThePlus =="1" || justThePlus =="2")
```

Other issues:

1. Double == sign
2. remove ; at the end of the if statement

To improve readability:

```
string[] allowedValues = { "+", "1", "2" };
if (allowedValues.Contains(justThePlus)) {
```

Answer (score 6):

OR statements need a condition either side:

```
if (justThePlus == "+" || justThePlus == "1" || ....)
```

Also:

- Use `==` instead of `=` for string comparison
- Remove semi-colon from the end of your if statement.

Answer (score 6):

You can use an array contains:

```
if (new[] { "+" ,  "1" ,  "2" ,  "3" ,  "4" ,  "5" ,  "6" , "7" ,  "8" ,  "9" , "0" }.Contains(justThePlus));
{

}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a different logic to achieve the same.

```
var validChars= "+1234567890" ;
if(justThePlus.Length==1 && validChars.IndexOf(justThePlus)>=0)
{
}
```

Comment: var validChars = "+0123456789".ToCharArray(); / Array.BinarySearch(validChars, justThePlus);

Answer (score 3):

I think you are making this way too hard.

```
// Ensures the string has 9 digits and optionally starts with a "+"
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^(\+)?([0-9]{9})");
string input;

while (!regex.IsMatch(input))
{
    Console.Write("Please enter your phone number: ");
    input = Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[`||` operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6373h346.aspx) expects both operand as a `bool` value. This operand performs  [logical-OR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OR_gate) between both operands.

As you can see, using this operator with `string` operands is meaningless.

You can put your all numbers and `+` sign in a `List<string>` and you can check it with [`Contains`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`Any`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) methods like;

```
var listOfNumbersAndPlus = new List<string>(){"+", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0"};
if(listOfNumbersAndPlus.Any(justThePlus.Contains))
```

Answer (score 2):

Phone numbers can be represented by *user* in *many different formats*, e.g.:

```
 +1(555)123-45-67
  8 555 123 45 67
     +75551234567
```

So I strongly suggest you using *regular expressions*; in your case it could be

https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/regular-expressions-cookbook/9781449327453/ch04s03.html

For instance

```
  Console.Write("Please enter your phone number: ");
  string input = Console.ReadLine();

  //TODO: you may want to update/change this pattern
  String pattern = "^\+(?:[0-9] ?){6,14}[0-9]$";

  Boolean isNumberValid = Regex.IsMatch(input, pattern);
```

Then, if `input` string is a valid one, you can just *collect* all digits within it with a help of *Linq*:

```
  // Standard phone number representation: e.g. 155512345678
  String stdNumber = new String(input.Where(ch => ch >= '0' && ch <= '9').ToArray());
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Regex to validate input.

```
var input = "+12345678";
var pattern = @"\+\d{8}"; // matches number, which is at leas 8-digit long and starts with '+' sign
var isValidNumber = Regex.IsMatch(input, pattern);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your question has been answered directly (justThePlus == "+" || justThePlus =="1"...). Here's a more efficient way to do the same thing:

```
    switch (justThePlus)
    {
        case "+" :
        case "0" :
        case "1" :
        case "2" :
        case "3" :
        case "4" :
        case "5" :
        case "6" :
        case "7" :
        case "8" :
        case "9" :
            // ???
            break;

        default :
            // ???
            break;

    }
```